# When to create a PHP extension?

Tags: php, php-extension

In what exact use cases should a developer create a PHP extension instead of PHP library?

From what I found on google (*very little is written on the subject*).

> PHP extensions are compiled libraries which enable specific functions to be used in your PHP code.

I also found that they are written in `C`.

- Why should I compile a library?
- What are the benefits over libraries?

If you could answer with an example, lets say `zeroMQ` or `mySQL` extension, that would be great.

Comment: From your question, an extension sounds like it is simply a collection of libraries, possibly that inter-relate to each other?

Comment: Anything that userland PHP code doesn't give you sufficient access to and/or that would be too slow in userland code.

Answer (score 2):

Main point of writing extension in C instead of library in PHP is speed and/or memory-wise optimization. You can leverage C's means of optimizations, which are not available in PHP.

A good example here would be [`BC Math`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension: most of the functionality could be written in pure PHP (although not all of it), but the main point here is the speed and memory-optimized computations.